# Show procedure/function code in MySql

Tags: mysql, function, schema, show, procedure

Is there any options to view stored procedure/function code in MySql same as like "sp_helptext procedurename" in sql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [View stored procedure/function definition in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968773/view-stored-procedure-function-definition-in-mysql)

Comment: `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION <function_name>`

Answer (score 18):

try "SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedurename"

Comment: **1.** SHOW with CREATE is usually available, (just SHOW is only available in debug mode)........................  **2.** This **shows the whole CREATE code** of the function/procedure.

Comment: Also note that of course you can switch `procedure` keyword with `function` to get the function create code::::: `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION function_name`

Answer (score 8):

Yes,

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='procedurename'
```

Comment: This **shows what the function/procedure CONTAINS** - what is to be executed, not the whole "create function/procedure" code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information form the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/routines-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting a bit, and I think one of the following two works best.

To list everything (`parameters`, `collating`, etc.), use this.

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA in (SELECT DATABASE()) AND ROUTINE_NAME='ProcedureName';
```

To list only the code, use this.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA in (SELECT DATABASE()) AND ROUTINE_NAME='ProcedureName';
```

In both of the above, the nested select is required to limit the result to the current database, since `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, being the system database, contains details for every database installed in the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to mySQL workbench

- Right click on procedure and then select **ALTER**. (This Will open the definition of procedure for you(is the easiest way).

**OR**

- You can also use the command, SHOW `CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name`;