# Copy stored procedure from one db to another in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I need to make a php script that can copy stored procedure and function from one database to another, how can i do this ?
The database is mysql and there 2 database are not on the same server

Comment: Hi! Please check [ask]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968773/view-stored-procedure-function-definition-in-mysql#answer-1968798

Comment: You'd better get writing some code then if you need it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View stored procedure/function definition in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968773/view-stored-procedure-function-definition-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE DB_Name.Procedure_Name;
use New_DB_Name
```

create procedure again.