# How to verify a password against MediaWiki user table hashed password?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, mediawiki

I am trying to combine my chat application login with my MediaWiki login. The chat application has an odd way of authenticating and I have modded it to work with a DB.

I am trying to match the password that the user inputs in the chat login with the one stored in the MediaWiki user table, but I cannot figure out how MediaWiki hashes its passwords. I do know that I am using the default salted hashing. Does anyone have a function that can recreate this?

I have tried:

```
hash('md5', $password);
```

but there is more to it that I cannot figure out.

Comment: Did you look at the media wiki source code?

Comment: yes but I am having trouble finding the encryption function

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:User_table

Comment: It's not encryption, it's hashing. There's a huge difference. Please stop calling hashing "encryption."

Comment: @Jack Eeeeek, they're using a general purpose hashing function.

Comment: saw this on a forum (couldn't find it in the code) this is why i called it encryption.... function wfEncryptPassword

Comment: @NullUserException It's a thing of beauty .. ahem ..

Comment: @arrowill12 Well, it's wrong. Encryption is reversible, hashing isn't.

Comment: This effectively gives the second application access to your users' passwords, which might be ok if you run said application but increases your attack surface anyway. Any reason not to use OAuth? You might want to add your use case to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager : user authentication in MediaWiki is being rewritten to make integration easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all straight off the top of my head, but:

```
<?php
//let's pretend these were entered by the user trying to authenticate
$username = 'ted';
$password = 'password';

//PDO-like syntax. I wrote my own class around it and I don't remember how to do it raw.
$query = "SELECT pw_hash FROM user_table WHERE username = ?";
$rs = $dbh->doQuery($query, array($username));
if( count($rs) == 0 ) { throw new Exception('no user'); }

//will be either
//:A:5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
//:B:838c83e1:e4ab7024509eef084cdabd03d8b2972c

$parts = explode(':', $rs[0]['pw_hash']);
print_r($parts); //$parts[0] will be blank because of leading ':'

switch($parts[1]) {
    case 'A':
        $given_hash = md5($password);
        $stored_hash = $parts[2];
        break;
    case 'B':
        $given_hash = md5($parts[2] . md5($password));
        $stored_hash = $parts[3];
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception('Unknown hash type');
        break;
}

if( $given_hash === $stored_hash) {
    echo "login was succesful.";
} else {
    echo "login failed.";
}
```

Props to Jack's comment on the question with [this link](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3aUser_table) to mediawiki docs.

Comment: this very helpful I am attempting to implement it now. the password is stored as a 'tiny blob' in the DB when i query for it will it get the hash or some binary?

Comment: Beats me. Try a `var_dump()` on the result set and [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql) to convert, if necessary.

Comment: I just `echo` the results and they are normal thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If [this wiki page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3aUser_table) is to be believed, to verify a password against the stored database value, you could do this:

```
list($dummy, $type, $salt, $hash) = explode(':', $db_password);

$pwd_hash = md5($user_password);
if ($type == 'B' && md5("$salt-$pwd_hash") === $hash) {
    // yay success, type B
} elseif ($type == 'A' && $salt === $pwd_hash) {
    // yay success, type A
} else {
    // password is wrong or stored password is in an unknown format
}
```

Assuming `$db_password` is the database value and `$user_password` is the supplied password to verify against.

Comment: "oops, sorry." could be either because the password format is invalid or because the password is wrong.