# BLOB to long text conversion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, blob

I have a column in MySQL which has the datatype BLOB. I am using Crystal Reports for some reports.

My problem is BLOB column will show blank data if it contains data other than  a picture.

The data I am getting from DB is text only. So I want to convert the BLOB column to some other datatype which will occupy more data like BLOB object.

Please suggest what datatype I can conevrt.

I tried this query but it is not working.

```
SELECT CAST(key_initiatives AS MEDIUMTEXT) key_init FROM OBJSETTING_FOCUS_ON_CUSTOMER
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT CAST(key_initiatives AS CHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 )  AS key_init FROM OBJSETTING_FOCUS_ON_CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Hi Ravi,This is working but I need to store as max characters as I can.How much data that we can store in this text ?.Please suggest is there any other possibilties

Comment: A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 – 1) characters.
you can see maximum length the data types http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: Hi Ravi can you please suggest how I can use text type in above query.Please help

Comment: @user2846028 I think query does the same thing what you expecting to use

Comment: Hi ravi I dint got what you are telling .Please explain

Comment: @user2846028 your question statement says to convert the Blob to longtext.I think the query does the pretty same thing

Comment: Hi Ravi so you mean to say I can take char also.Suppose if the data is more than 255 characters Will I get the data as char will hold only 255 characters