# How can I convert BLOB to text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, text, blob

I have a BLOB field in one of tables and I used the following command to convert it to text:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD COLUMN field1_new TEXT;

update mytable set
field1_new = CONVERT(field1 USING utf8);
```

This did not work and gave me some random characters. Like:

```
9x
```

This result is returned as a content of message which does not make sense. I changed the character set to 'latin1'. This one gave me a larger sequence of characters yet still something non-sense. For example:

```
¢xœ}T]k1|/ô?¬Á/‡ZJpMK“–<$„Ô¥ôqO§»ÑI®¤³¹ß...
```

Is there anyway to figure out what character set the BLOB field is using so that I can convert it to text properly?

Any help with this problem will be much appreciated. Thanks

Edited: I have to also mention that I used CAST command and it returned:

```
�x�}T]k1|/�?��/��ZJpMK��<$�ԥ�qO���I������������$:���̬�4�...
```

Comment: I just tried your query and it worked in my test table. Could your data be corrupted?

Comment: Since another group have done it once I guess the data is not corrupted.

Comment: Would you like it dumped in HEX?  Or maybe it is really TEXT and you are asking to _interpret_ it in some `CHARACTER SET`?

Answer (score 2):

try using `cast`:

```
CAST(field1 AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
```

you can see this post also for more:[How do I convert from BLOB to TEXT in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql)