# Fetch Data from Mysql in php on pdf using fpdf

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I am new in php, and using first time FPDF for generating pdf file.
I have a database with name `test123` and table with named `form` having four fields
`id` with data type int,
`Name`, `Address` and `Designation` with data type Varchar, and the last one is Text with data type longblob.

Data inserted in these fields by a form having textarea.

Problem is that when I want to generate pdf file and import data from database data type blob is not converted. Here is screenshot of my problem just click on the link [http://postimg.org/image/qtid90tqb](http://postimg.org/image/qtid90tqb/)/

Below is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

//create a FPDF object
$pdf=new FPDF(); 

//set font for the entire document
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',20);
//$pdf->SetTextColor(50,60,100);

//set up a page
$pdf->AddPage('P'); 
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('default');

//insert an image and make it a link
$pdf->Image('image/logo.gif',100,10,20,0);

//display the title with a border around it
$pdf->SetXY(40,30);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(50,60,100);
$pdf->Write(10,'The Pakistan Credit Rating Agency Limited',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Line(10,40,200,40);

//Set x and y position for the main text, reduce font size and write content
$pdf->SetXY (20,45);
$pdf->SetFontSize(10);
$pdf->SetTextColor(30,30,100);
$pdf->Write(5,'NL FYI s-l4l (PSO-040515)');

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test123"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="form"; // Table name

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,"test123");

$sql="SELECT * FROM form WHERE id = '30'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($rows= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
{           
    $name = $rows['Name'];
    $address = $rows['Address'];
    $class = $rows['Designation'];
    $phone = $rows['Text'];

    $pdf->SetXY (20,60);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(12);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->Write(7,$name);
    $pdf->SetXY (20,65);
    $pdf->Write(7,$address);
    $pdf->SetXY (20,70);
    $pdf->Write(7,$class);
    $pdf->SetXY (20,90);
    $pdf->Write(7,$phone);
    $pdf->Ln(); 
}

//Output the document
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','I');     
?>
```

Comment: $phone = $rows['Text'];
$text = $row['Text'];
why are you using Test column two times in different while loop??

Comment: @habibulhaq i remove $text = $row['Text']; but its not working yet.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql

Comment: Your *$_rows['Text']* is html code that you are outputting with just *->Write()*. You need to use an expanded version of *->WriteHTML()*, for example you could use http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php

Comment: @habibulhaq dear i cant understand this topic nad the tag given here is not working in my cae :(

Comment: @Sean Dear its shown error. :(

Comment: `its shown error`. Not sure what you mean. Also, you have `$html2pdf->WriteHTML($text);`, but I don't see where you have set `$html2pdf` only `$pdf`. Also, you have 2 fetches `while($rows= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)))` and `while($row= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)))`. The 2nd one won't have anything to fetch, as the 1st one fetched them all. You either need to query again before fetching, or do a `data_seek()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$s = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM form WHERE id = '30'");
oci_execute( $s);
$result = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array( $s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {   
$result[] = $row;   }

$pdf->Cell(20,5,'Name',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(20,5,$result[]['Name'],1,0,'C',0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$pdf->Output();     
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require("DB.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
$header = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='blog' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='student'");

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
}
foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
        $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: DBController is just a function.