# How to retrieve binary file data as converted char in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I'm working on a project that deals with text files that are to be stored in a database.

So i'm using the `blob` data type, that converts the files into binary and then uploads to MySQL.

My problem is how to convert the entire binary text into char while retrieving it? I tried the php command below but it doesn't seem to work well. Please help.

```
SELECT cast(blob-col_name as char(1000000)) from `table_name`
```

[The output retrieves garbage text as shown in the image below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKzkP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert from BLOB to TEXT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql)

Comment: if it's only text files, you should consider using a TEXT-field instead.

Comment: @FranzGleichman the TEXT-field option works well but i have to upload documents in the database as part of the requirements which doesn't go with this option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(blob-col_name AS CHAR(1000000) CHARACTER SET utf8) As BLOBText FROM table_name;
```

**UPDATE**

```
$sql = "SELECT Legislation_ID, Legislation_Name, Category, 
        CAST(data AS CHAR(1000000) CHARACTER SET utf8) As BLOBText FROM legislations";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    file_put_contents($rows["Legislation_Name"].".zip", $rows["BLOBText"]);
    echo "<textarea style='height:500px;width:300px'>".$rows["BLOBText"]."</textarea><br/>";

}
```

Comment: How you retreive datas ? what is the code your are using with PHP ?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT `Legislation_ID`, `Legislation_Name`, `Category`, CAST(`data` AS CHAR(1000000) CHARACTER SET utf8) As BLOBText FROM `legislations`";

Comment: I used the above query and made a table to print all the results. But the data field comes out blank in the output.

Comment: I updated the code, try it like that, retreive it like this: `$row["BLOBText"]`

Comment: Yes the query works. But now its printing garbage text in the output field :|

Comment: Nope, still the same thing.

Comment: I have edited the post with an image link that displays the query results.

Comment: Add this line to your code: `file_put_contents($rows["Legislation_Name"].".zip", $rows["BLOBText"]);` the contents shown is in zip file and not in text file (This mean you saved a zip file in the blob column).

Comment: No, i converted my text file to .sql before uploading into the blob column. It wasn't a zip file

Comment: You store your file in doc/docx format no ? if yes then make what i told to you, change only extension to : `.doc` / `.docx` and not with `.zip`.

Comment: If you want return directly a TEXT from your BLOB Column, you have to store files created with block note / notepad etc ... in `.txt` format.

Comment: And i needed to know one more thing if i could do any formatting and encoding to the text because it dumps all the text directly in the output field.

Comment: Please make another question about your problem, this post not related to this.